# Auth guard('web') not working in laravel 6.2

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-6.2

I am using a client project that UI is being change. so its **Auth::guard('web')** was working in client server. but when i try to used that project into my **wamp server( localhost )** then it is not working. it is not returning login user data but it is returning data into **LoginController**. whole code is working in client server (shared server). so when its controller gone change then it not return data. it's before i did not faced this problem any more. i search in google and done many changes for solve this but not get my solution.  my **laravel version is 6.2**. so i came here. plz do not down vote...

plz help.

> **auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
 .....

  'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
```

> **route.php**

```
  Route::get('/','IndexController@index');  // here i am calling auth guard .
  Route::get('',['as'=>'posts','uses'=>'IndexController@index']);
```

> LoginController.php

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate($request, [
    'login'    => 'required',
    'password' => 'required',
]);

$login_type = filter_var($request->input('login'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) 
    ? 'email' 
    : 'username';

$request->merge([
    $login_type => $request->input('login')
]);

if (Auth::attempt($request->only($login_type, 'password'))) {
       
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        $previous_session = Auth::User()->session_id;
        if ($previous_session) {
            Session::getHandler()->destroy($previous_session);
        }

        Auth::user()->session_id = Session::getId();
        Auth::user()->save();
     
        $user = auth()->guard('web')->user();
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
        
        return response()->json([
            'status'        => 'S',
            'message' => 'Login Successfuly.'
        ], 201);

  }

return response()->json([
        'status'        => 'F',
        'message' => 'Unauthorized - Password Not matched.'
    ], 401);
```

}

> **IndexController**

```
# for Test login 
   if(  Auth::guard('web')->user())
    {
        return Auth::guard('web')->user();
    }
```

Comment: i was getting CSRF token 419 error . so i ignored csrf token form  VerifyCsrfToken

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem with help of my friend..
problem was in env file.

```
APP_URL=localhost
```

so basic logic is that you have to run **php artisan serve** that will give you **localhost**.so after that you will be able to get Auth data.

So when you face null from **Auth::user()** then check **APP_URL** in your **env file**.

wrong **APP_URL** will give you **CSRF token** error.

Comment: yes , answer was helpful for me. i fixed my issue like this.

Comment: nice solution bro.. thanks  for detail. i got my answer. love you.